# unauthorized: master key is required on aggregate ParseQuery PHP SDK

Tags: php, mongodb, parse-server

We use `parse/php-sdk` for accessing MongoDB

I get `unauthorized: master key is required` error when I try to do aggregate ParseQuery as below.

```
ParseClient::initialize('appId', null, 'masterKey');
ParseClient::setServerURL('https://example.com', 'mountPath');

$pipeline = [
    'group' => [
        'userAttached' => $userId,
        'total' => [ '$sum' => 1]
    ]
];

$query = new ParseQuery("Financials");
$query->equalTo("company_id", $companyId);
$query->equalTo("type", "income");

try {
    $resultSum = $query->aggregate($pipeline);
    print_r($resultSum);
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

As you can see master key is already set, can't find what may be the issue.

Comment: You may have found a bug, Would you mind to open an issue in the php open source repo? https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I did, thanks for the hint